# Не компилируется проект android studio из-за ошибки build.gradle

Tags: java, android-studio, компиляция

Согласно руководству https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru

Для работы материальных карточек необходимо установить зависимость в build.gradle.
После добавления зависимостей данный файл стал выглядеть так:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Однако при компиляции выдает ошибку

```
Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.3.0] on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@6169f20c.
```

Как решить данную проблему?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

нужно размещать эту зависимость в файл *build.gradle* модуля, а не всего приложения. Он находится не в корне проекта, а в папке *app/* (или как ваш модуль называется)

[image: scrn]

Answer (score 0):

В комментах в приведённом вами файле чётко сказано

> ```
>    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
>     // in the individual module build.gradle files
> ```

т.е. вы поместили вашу зависимость не в gradle файл модуля, а в файл проекта.

Вам надо поместить зависимость в файл модуля.