# Вопрос по настройке SDK Android

Tags: android, android-sdk

Вопрос заключается в следующем. На данный момент максимально-доступная версия платформы 6.0. У меня не телефоне 4.4.2. Это значит,что мне нужно устанавливать sdk для 4 версии, или я могу поставить и разработать приложение на 6-й и оно запустится на моем телефоне? Если первый вариант, тогда sdk какой версии будет универсальнее?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В среде разработки (например Android Studio) имеет смысл устанавливать последнюю стабильную версию SDK (на сегодняшний день - API 23 Android 6.0) - это позволит разрабатывать приложение с максимальным количеством поддерживаемых устройств и использовать возможности новых API для поддерживающих их устройств. То же самое относится и к пакетам SDK Tools, SDK Build Tools, SDK Platform Tools. Также должны быть установлены SDK, для которых будут созданы **виртуальные устройства** для тестирования. Прочие версии SDK, в том числе и реальных тестирующих устройств, устанавливать нет никакой необходимости - реальное устройство имеет все необходимое SDK в себе самом.
SDK устанавливается с помощью утилиты SDK Manager (*Tools -> Android -> SDK Manager* в Android Studio).

Разрабатываемое приложение при этом может быть запущено на любом устройстве, API которого выше, чем установленное в настройках проекта `minSdkVersion`, верхнее ограничение, как правило, не указывается. Указав данный параметр, вы будете иногда получать предупреждения от IDE о том, что пытаетесь использовать классы или методы, которые не совместимы с указанным минимальным API. Это значит, что данный класс (метод) был добавлен в SDK позднее, чем указанное вами ограничение и на некоторых устройствах из указанных в число поддерживаемых приложение работать не будет. [Библиотеки поддержки Google](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html?hl=ru) существенно расширяют возможности по использованию новых классов на устройствах, где имеющийся у них API не позволяет их использовать. При этом вместо классов SDK используются классы из support-библиотек.

Для того, чтобы указать, с каким минимальным API может работать ваше приложение (на какой минимальной версии Android оно может быть запущено), нужно указать это в конфигах вашего проекта **одним из** способов:

1. [Соответствующий параметр](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) в файле [*AndroidManifest.xml*](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

Пример указания в манифесте:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.application" />
    <uses-sdk 
      android:minSdkVersion="15"
      android:compileSdkVersion="23" />
<!-- остальное содержимое-->
</manifest>
```

2. В [секции *defaultConfig*](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html?hl=ru) конфигурационного файла *build.gradle* [модуля проекта](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/529621/177345).

Пример в файле build.gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.3'
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.application"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
    }
```

C переходом на систему сборки Gradle рекомендуется использовать второй вариант. Данные настройки в проекте означают, что приложение может быть запущенно на любом устройстве с Android 4.0 (API15) или новее.
Настроить эти параметры можно как непосредственным редактированием конфигурационных файлов, так и в окне Project Structure через графический интерфейс:

[image: scrn]

PS: `compileSdkVersion` (указывает с помощью какого SDK собирать проект) должна быть последней версии API, иначе новые библиотеки поддержки не будут работать (мажорный номер библиотеки поддержки и `compileSdkVersion` должны соответствовать).

`targetSdkVersion` указывает основное целевое устройство (предпочтительный для приложения SDK). Второстепенный параметр, но традиционно указывается равным `compileSdkVersion`

Answer (score 4):

Есть `minSdkVersion` и `targetSdkVersion`. `targetSdkVersion` желательно должна быть последней из доступных, а вот `minSdkVersion` Вы задаете начиная с какой версии Ваша программа будет работать (ну и использовать необходимо, соответственно, методы и пр. доступные начиная с этой версии).

Если будет `minSdkVersion 14`, то будет работать на всех устройствах, начиная с Android 4.0. Если `minSdkVersion 19`, то с Android 5.0 и т.п.

Благодаря наличию `Support` библиотек, Вы можете значительно понижать `minSdkVersion`, практически ничего не теряя, но если Вы хотите разрабатывать только под новые устройства, используя последние API, тогда на старых версиях, само собой, программа не будет работать.

Comment: Все верно, только не *Compat*, а *support*. AppCompat - это только одна из библиотек совместимости, которая реализует Material Design на устройствах ниже API 19. А библиотек поддержки [достаточно много (около 20-ти)](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/features.html) и помимо этой.

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за поправку, у меня просто отложилось из когда-то прочитанного, что `Compat`,  от слова "Compatibility" - совместимость, вот и называю их обобщенно все Compat

Comment: а где можно посмотреть minSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion?в sdk менеджере есть вкладки Tools,preview channel, версии систем и extraz. при создании проекта можно выбрать только нужную sdk и все..то,о чем вы написали я не нахожу..

Comment: @Iga при создании Вы указываете `minSdkVersion`. А в проекте в `build.gradle`(Module: app) смотрите

Comment: открыл ide. нашел где можно выбрать minsdkversion, а вот в грейдле по умолчанию значатся только: buildscript,allprojects ,task clean(type: Delete). про версии там я ничего не увидел

Comment: @Iga Смотреть надо в конфиге модуля, а не всего проекта

Answer (score 4):

Если хотите тестировать на своем телефоне, то `minSdkVersion` должна быть <= 19. Иначе не получится запустить программу на телефоне. `targetSdkVersion` может быть вплоть до самой последней, но >= `minSdkVersion`. Обычно и выбирают последнюю версию SDK. Если будете публиковать ваше приложение, то желательно тестировать его на телефонах, планшетах разных версий SDK и разрешений экранов. Без эмулятора не обойтись.

Чем меньшее значение в качестве `minSdkVersion` выберете, тем большую долю существующих в мире устройств охватите (см. [Dashboards](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?hl=ru)). Но тем сложнее будет и разработка (больше ограничений, необходимость учесть разные варианты) и тестирование. Нужен компромисс.

Оба параметра (`minSdkVersion`, `targetSdkVersion`) выставляются в файле `build.gradle(Module:app)`. Можно найти этот файл быстро, если смотреть проект в режиме Android в AndroidStudio (В разделе Gradle Scripts). После его исправления нужно выполнить синхронизацию проекта с Gradle файлами (Sync project with Gradle Files) -  на панели иконка- зеленый кружок и голубая стрелочка вниз.

Comment: Учитывая, что все API < 16 занимают менее 3%, то компромисс не большой получается :)